# Submitting HTML with inline styles for emails with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Is there some HTML editor for Vue which make all styles inline?
Like:

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 24px">Subject</h1>
<p>Example of <span style="color: red;">text</span></p>
```

Basically it requires for email magazines where we can't use stylesheets, herewith website admin must can input the email content in WISYWIG-mode.

**Please note that this question is NOT about [inline styles binding in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)**.

Also I know that to submit email we need the server, so current question is about how to submit HTML with `style` attributes to backend.

Comment: I don't know any wysiwyg editors that generates style-sheets for the edits. All of them at-least those I've used generates inline styles only. Which one is you using that is generating style-sheets?

Comment: @MatJ Thank you for the comment. Currently I am using the CK Editor (for Vue).

Comment: CKEditor generates stylesheets instead of inline styles?

Comment: @MatJ, I did not find the actual reliable information about it's possible...